# Import Data in cplex from excel (xlsx file)

Tags: excel, cplex

I have an excel table and I want to put one column of this table in a vector in .dat file.
Here is what I have :
First solution with the complete path :
SheetConnection sheet("C:\Users\Hor246\opl\Bushfire\month_01_omission.xlsx");
Value from SheetRead(sheet,"month_01_omission!B2:B431");
Second solution with the name :
SheetConnection sheet("month_01.xlsx");
lat from SheetRead(sheet,"month_01!A2:A855856");
In both cases, when I run the project, cplex says"Value/lat is not defined"
Do you know what is the problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should declare your Value and lat in your .mod

See for example the oil [example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplexamples/topics/opl_mp_examples_where.html) in CPLEX

You have

```
{string} Oils = ...;
```

in the .mod and then

```
Oils from SheetRead(sheet,"'oil data'!A2:A4");
```

in the .dat